# How to manage R extension / package documentation with grace (or at least without pain)

Tags: r, package

Now and then I embrace project specific code in R packages. I use the documentation files as suggested by [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) to document the application of the code.

So once you set up your project and did all the editing to the .Rd files,
how do you manage a painless and clean versioning without rewriting or intense copy-pasting of all the documentation files in case of code or, even worse, code structure changes?

To be more verbose, my current workflow is that I issue `package.skeleton()`, do the editing on the .Rd-files followed by `R CMD check` and `R CMD build`. When I do changes to my code I need to redo the above maybe appending '.2.0.1' or whatever in order to preserve the precursor version. Before running the `R CMD check` command I need to repopulate all the .Rd-files with great care in order to get a clean check and succsessful compilation of Tex-files. This is really silly and sometimes a real pain, e.g. if you want to address all the warnings or latex has a bad day.

What tricks do you use? Please share your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is `roxygen2`.

RStudio provides a [handy guide](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/packages/documentation), but briefly you document your function in-line with the function definition:

```
#' Function doing something
#' Extended description goes here
#' @param x Input foo blah
#' @return A numeric vector length one containing foo
myFunc <- function(x) NULL
```

If you're using RStudio (and maybe ESS also?) the Build Package command automagically creates the .Rd files for you.  If not, you can read the `roxygen2` documentation for the commands to generate the docs.